# Help with Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need some suggestions in writing a regular expression pattern

My string would be of this format

number_text_date_time.xml

i.e.: 35068_Started_20110304_081920.xml

Number 5 characters ,"Text" can be of this format, "Date" in yyyymmdd format, "time" in HHMMSS format

One requirement I have is, the TEXT in the name of the file has to be checked against a predefined list. Ex: Text can contain only STARTED, CLOSED, OPENED, NOT-OK etc

How can I write a Generic expression for this considering the fact that I also have to check the TEXT against predefined list

Thank in advance

Karthik

Comment: I would start with `filename.split('_')` and work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully tested; line breaks for clarity only:

```
(?<number>\d{5})_
(?<text>STARTED|CLOSED|OPENED|NOT-OK)_
(?<date>(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))_
(?<time>(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\d)[0-5]\d[0-5]\d).xml
```

I turned on the Case Insensitive option to match your string.

With help from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) and http://regexlib.com/

Comment: Excellent. Beat me to it, +1.

Comment: Thank you so much. Seems to be working. Would it be possible for you explain the following: (?<date>(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))_(?<time>(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\d)[0-5]\d[0-5]\d) Basically the date and time check. Thank you

Comment: You could do it a lot simpler, such as \d{8}, but this does some validation (not 100%) to insure a valid date/time. For instance, it assumes years are 19xx or 20xx. If you're validating it elsewhere, you could go the simple route.